# Water leak where the gutter attaches to the fascia

Tags: water, water-damage, gutters, fascia

We recently replaced the roof and installed new gutters. One month later I have a water leak where the gutter attaches to the fascia. What can be the reason?

Comment: Someone goofed.  If done by contractor have them back.  Without pictures not much we can tell or help with.

Comment: Could be a number of reasons.  The roofer may have left off a drip rail.  The downspout could be blocked.  The gutter could be pitched the wrong way.  The gutter could be too small for the amount of runoff.

Comment: Detailed close photos would help here. As others have written, perhaps the layers of shingles and flashing were not installed right. Perhaps something has failed. Perhaps the gutters/downspouts have clogged and backed up. Running a hose onto the roof or gutter near the leak area can help you replicate and track down the issue.